# Are google analytics capable of measuring these kind of informations?

Tags: google-analytics

Our application is written in React (frontend) and NodeJS (backend), we have 2 roles in the application, host and audience. Host can access host page (i.e. domain/host/{eventId}), while audience can access audience page (i.e. domain/audience/{eventId}.

Since I have never used google analytics, I was wondering is it possible to track how many hosts navigated to host page while more than 10 audience members are active in audience page using google analytics? Also, is it possible to track if host was more than 10 minutes on specific URL (for example domain/host/{eventId})?

Answer (score 0):

For first question you have to check users number in Analytics i.e. with a segment which specifies the path you are interested in.

For the second you Havre to set an event time based to send to Analytics after 10 minutes from opening the page. Then you can find that aggregated data in the reports.